# window.location.hash won't alert in iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, iframe, hash

See code below: I want Page 1 to alert "#testing"...

This works in C and FF but not in IE :S

**Page 1:**

This is the page that will be visited

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://page2.com/#testing"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2:**

This is the page of the iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
alert(window.location.hash);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you dont try jquery?

Comment: I want to do it in simple javascript...

Comment: @MaziarBouali can you post solution with jQuery?

Comment: @user1087110 which version of IE you are using? I've tested it with IE7 and IE8 and it works for me.

Comment: For me it doesn't work in IE8 or IE 9. Forgot to mention that page 1 and page 2 are on different domains, but I don't see how it will differ. I cant figure this out!

Comment: Did you try to load the page directly. i.e. not inside iframe Does it work when not embedded in iframe?

Comment: I forgot to add window.onload... "window.onload = function(){
alert(window.location.hash);}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `window.frameElement.contentWindow.location.hash` in IE

Comment: No, there is no error message. There is even an alert box, but there is no text in it...

Comment: I solved it "window.onload = function(){ alert(window.location.hash);}"

Answer (score 2):

I confirm the problem! `location.hash` and `window.location.hash` are just empty if page is within cross-domain iframe in IE9 (didn't tested in older versions)!